# How to suppress carriage return after a variable?

Tags: python

Don't flame but I'm still a python newbie. I need to suppress the carriage return after I display a variable.

```
data = """
[virtual_machines: %s]
    \taddress %s.domain.com
""" % (line, line)

fg = file('munin.txt', 'a')
fg.write(stuff)
```

When printing this out, it creates a new line after the variable gets printed. I tried using %r but that displays the "\n" code.

Edit: I'm actually trying to write it into another file.

Comment: Instead of having to double the `line` argument, you could either use the new string formatting syntax using the `format()` method or a `strings.Template` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are seeing a new-line after the %s. It looks like `line`  may have a newline in it, in which case you can do `line.strip()` to remove all whitespace around it:

```
... " % (line.strip(), line.strip())
```

or

```
 ... " % (line.strip(), ) * 2
```

If you are seeing an unwanted newline at the end of the whole thing, it is because you have a newline in your multi-line string and should refer to Jared Updike's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
data = """
[virtual_machines: %s]
    \taddress %s.domain.com""" % (line, line)
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you printing this out?

If you are using `print`, simply append a trailing comma:

```
print data,
```

which will suppress the newline.

Comment: Actually, writing it into another file, sorry about that. I've updated my post.